# Model to Model Transformation Techniques or Design Pattern in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, django-modeltranslation

I have come across a requirement where I need to come up with a Generic framework for transforming one Model to another Model and it should work for any model to any model transformation. So, It will have input model type and output model type.

I know for that purpose, We need to have a mapping file for defining mapping of types in Model.

So, I was just wondering it is a well known problem. So, there must be solution available for this already or any pattern which handles it very nicely.

Comment: [any good](http://automapper.org/)?

Comment: @qujck I couldn't get you is there anything obscure to you

Comment: I don't understand quite well your question. Are you looking for a object-to-object mapping, if this is the case, Automapper could be your solution.